# Add jesperReports into the Jar file in java to run other computers

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I make a project in netbeans including jasperreports and then I covert project to jar file. i want when i run the jar file of project the jasperReports file also work fine....... but for this I used the following code 
the exception is come... from code...

I try the following code

//code

```
InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Users/Kashif/Desktop/Muhammad Kashif/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Torch/Reports/report11.jrxml");
                 JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put("Discount", para);
            map.put("Customer", para1);
            map.put("Total", para2);

            JasperReport jasperReport =  JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, con);

            //view report to UI
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
```

//error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:305)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:284)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:273)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:247)
    at torch.UserGui.printBtnActionPerformed(UserGui.java:1269)
.....
.....
.....
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:619)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:297)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:524)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: What JAR file do you mean? Where does this exception come from?

Comment: Jar file mean I make a project in netbeans including jasperreports and then I covert project to jar file. i want when i run the jar file of project the jasperReports file also work fine....... but for this I used the code that is given in question....  the exception is come... from code...

Comment: I meant in which environment the exception comes up. Where do you deploy the JAR file? That the exception comes from the code is obviously no big surprise.

Answer (score 0):

The exception might come because of a missing `jrxml` file.

You have to make sure that wherever you deploy your JAR file (not clearly understandable) this relative path and file (no preceding slash!) exists:

`Users/Kashif/Desktop/Muhammad Kashif/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Torch/Reports/report11.jrxml`

For example, if you deploy on a Linux server in your home path, you have to make sure there is a file in

`/home/username/Users/Kashif/Desktop/Muhammad Kashif/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Torch/Reports/report11.jrxml`

On Windows, you have to make sure that the file is lying underneath your directory structure, e.g.

`C:\mypath\java -jar xyz.jar`

`C:\mypath\java\Users/Kashif/Desktop/Muhammad Kashif/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Torch/Reports/report11.jrxml`